# How to create triangle on div without using :after?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create below style with CSS.

[image]

Below code works fine:

```
.my-class:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -16px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 18px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
      border-left: 17px solid $explainStageTailBkColor;
      z-index: 2;
      transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
    }
```

I am using `reactjs` and I need to set the code at runtime. Since react doesn't support updating Pseudo-elements styles, I have to use a regular dom for that. How can I make a regular dom to a triangle style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use by using class with `position:absolute`

I posted an example below

Hope it will help

```css
.my-class {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  background: tomato;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid tomato;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <span class="corner"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using [CSS `transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=control)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: black;
}
div div {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
  
div div:first-child {
  width: 1.5em;
}
div div:nth-child(2n) {
  transform: rotateZ( 45deg ) scale( .7 );
}
```

```html
<div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .my-class {
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      height: 20px;
      background: tomato;
    }

    .corner {
      position: absolute;
      right: -30px;
      top: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid tomato;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    <div class="my-class">
      <span class="corner"></span>
    </div>
```

You can use by using class with position:absolute
you need to transform your child div in -90deg than it looks like a triangle.
Here is new code I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ha Ha dude copy and paste answer with some changes.. GOOD !